# Error 403 while executing WordCount on Google Cloud Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to execute the Word Count example of Google Cloud Dataflow:

```
$ OUTPUT=gs://xxx-dataflow/output.txt
$ STAGING=gs://xxx-dataflow/staging
$ PROJECT=our_project_id
$ mvn exec:java -pl examples   -Dexec.mainClass=com.google.cloud.dataflow.examples.WordCount   -Dexec.args="--project=${PROJECT} --stagingLocation=${STAGING} --runner=BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner --output=${OUTPUT}"
```

Unfortunately, I am getting an error:

```
hh-MacBook-Air:DataflowJavaSDK poiuytrez$ mvn exec:java -pl examples   -Dexec.mainClass=com.google.cloud.dataflow.examples.WordCount   -Dexec.args="--project=${PROJECT} --stagingLocation=${STAGING} --runner=BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner --output=${OUTPUT}"
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Google Cloud Dataflow Java Examples - All manual_build
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> exec-maven-plugin:1.1:java (default-cli) > validate @ google-cloud-dataflow-java-examples-all >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< exec-maven-plugin:1.1:java (default-cli) < validate @ google-cloud-dataflow-java-examples-all <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.1:java (default-cli) @ google-cloud-dataflow-java-examples-all ---
Mar 26, 2015 12:10:37 PM com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineRunner fromOptions
INFO: PipelineOptions.filesToStage was not specified. Defaulting to files from the classpath: will stage 41 files. Enable logging at DEBUG level to see which files will be staged.
Mar 26, 2015 12:10:38 PM com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineRunner run
INFO: Executing pipeline on the Dataflow Service, which will have billing implications related to Google Compute Engine usage and other Google Cloud Services.
Mar 26, 2015 12:10:38 PM com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.PackageUtil stageClasspathElementsToGcs
INFO: Uploading 41 files from PipelineOptions.filesToStage to GCS to prepare for execution in the cloud.
Mar 26, 2015 12:10:40 PM com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.RetryHttpRequestInitializer$LoggingHttpBackoffUnsuccessfulResponseHandler handleResponse
WARNING: Request failed with code 403, will NOT retry: https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/xxx-dataflow/o?name=staging/classes-YVxGau7wqYUa4UjU1KkEAg.zip&uploadType=resumable
Mar 26, 2015 12:10:40 PM com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel$UploadOperation run
SEVERE: Upload failure
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Forbidden",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Forbidden"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:423)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel$UploadOperation.run(GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Mar 26, 2015 12:10:40 PM com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.PackageUtil stageClasspathElementsToGcs
WARNING: Upload attempt failed, sleeping before retrying staging of classpath: /Users/poiuytrez/Documents/xxx/datascience/DataflowJavaSDK/examples/target/classes
java.io.IOException: Failed to write to GCS path gs://xxx-dataflow/staging/classes-YVxGau7wqYUa4UjU1KkEAg.zip.
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel.throwIfUploadFailed(GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel.java:373)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel.close(GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel.java:270)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.PackageUtil.stageClasspathElementsToGcs(PackageUtil.java:159)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.PackageUtil.stageClasspathElementsToGcs(PackageUtil.java:105)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.GcsStager.stageFiles(GcsStager.java:44)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineRunner.run(DataflowPipelineRunner.java:165)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.run(BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.java:96)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.run(BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.java:47)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:145)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.examples.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:290)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Forbidden",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Forbidden"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:423)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel$UploadOperation.run(GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more

Mar 26, 2015 12:10:45 PM com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.RetryHttpRequestInitializer$LoggingHttpBackoffUnsuccessfulResponseHandler handleResponse
WARNING: Request failed with code 403, will NOT retry: https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/xxx-dataflow/o?name=staging/classes-YVxGau7wqYUa4UjU1KkEAg.zip&uploadType=resumable
Mar 26, 2015 12:10:45 PM com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel$UploadOperation run
SEVERE: Upload failure
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Forbidden",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Forbidden"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:423)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel$UploadOperation.run(GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Mar 26, 2015 12:10:45 PM com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.PackageUtil stageClasspathElementsToGcs
WARNING: Upload attempt failed, sleeping before retrying staging of classpath: /Users/poiuytrez/Documents/xxx/datascience/DataflowJavaSDK/examples/target/classes
java.io.IOException: Failed to write to GCS path gs://xxx-dataflow/staging/classes-YVxGau7wqYUa4UjU1KkEAg.zip.
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel.throwIfUploadFailed(GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel.java:373)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel.close(GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel.java:270)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.PackageUtil.stageClasspathElementsToGcs(PackageUtil.java:159)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.PackageUtil.stageClasspathElementsToGcs(PackageUtil.java:105)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.GcsStager.stageFiles(GcsStager.java:44)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineRunner.run(DataflowPipelineRunner.java:165)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.run(BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.java:96)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.run(BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.java:47)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:145)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.examples.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:290)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Forbidden",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Forbidden"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:423)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel$UploadOperation.run(GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more

Mar 26, 2015 12:10:54 PM com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.RetryHttpRequestInitializer$LoggingHttpBackoffUnsuccessfulResponseHandler handleResponse
WARNING: Request failed with code 403, will NOT retry: https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/xxx-dataflow/o?name=staging/classes-YVxGau7wqYUa4UjU1KkEAg.zip&uploadType=resumable
Mar 26, 2015 12:10:54 PM com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel$UploadOperation run
SEVERE: Upload failure
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Forbidden",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Forbidden"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:423)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel$UploadOperation.run(GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Mar 26, 2015 12:10:54 PM com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.PackageUtil stageClasspathElementsToGcs
WARNING: Upload attempt failed, sleeping before retrying staging of classpath: /Users/poiuytrez/Documents/xxx/datascience/DataflowJavaSDK/examples/target/classes
java.io.IOException: Failed to write to GCS path gs://xxx-dataflow/staging/classes-YVxGau7wqYUa4UjU1KkEAg.zip.
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel.throwIfUploadFailed(GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel.java:373)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel.close(GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel.java:270)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.PackageUtil.stageClasspathElementsToGcs(PackageUtil.java:159)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.PackageUtil.stageClasspathElementsToGcs(PackageUtil.java:105)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.GcsStager.stageFiles(GcsStager.java:44)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineRunner.run(DataflowPipelineRunner.java:165)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.run(BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.java:96)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.run(BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.java:47)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:145)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.examples.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:290)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Forbidden",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Forbidden"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:423)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel$UploadOperation.run(GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more

Mar 26, 2015 12:11:04 PM com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.RetryHttpRequestInitializer$LoggingHttpBackoffUnsuccessfulResponseHandler handleResponse
WARNING: Request failed with code 403, will NOT retry: https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/xxx-dataflow/o?name=staging/classes-YVxGau7wqYUa4UjU1KkEAg.zip&uploadType=resumable
Mar 26, 2015 12:11:04 PM com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel$UploadOperation run
SEVERE: Upload failure
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Forbidden",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Forbidden"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:423)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel$UploadOperation.run(GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Mar 26, 2015 12:11:04 PM com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.PackageUtil stageClasspathElementsToGcs
WARNING: Upload attempt failed, sleeping before retrying staging of classpath: /Users/poiuytrez/Documents/xxx/datascience/DataflowJavaSDK/examples/target/classes
java.io.IOException: Failed to write to GCS path gs://xxx-dataflow/staging/classes-YVxGau7wqYUa4UjU1KkEAg.zip.
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel.throwIfUploadFailed(GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel.java:373)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel.close(GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel.java:270)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.PackageUtil.stageClasspathElementsToGcs(PackageUtil.java:159)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.PackageUtil.stageClasspathElementsToGcs(PackageUtil.java:105)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.GcsStager.stageFiles(GcsStager.java:44)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineRunner.run(DataflowPipelineRunner.java:165)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.run(BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.java:96)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.run(BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.java:47)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:145)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.examples.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:290)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Forbidden",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Forbidden"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:423)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel$UploadOperation.run(GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more

Mar 26, 2015 12:11:27 PM com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.RetryHttpRequestInitializer$LoggingHttpBackoffUnsuccessfulResponseHandler handleResponse
WARNING: Request failed with code 403, will NOT retry: https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/xxx-dataflow/o?name=staging/classes-YVxGau7wqYUa4UjU1KkEAg.zip&uploadType=resumable
Mar 26, 2015 12:11:27 PM com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel$UploadOperation run
SEVERE: Upload failure
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Forbidden",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Forbidden"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:423)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel$UploadOperation.run(GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Mar 26, 2015 12:11:27 PM com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.PackageUtil stageClasspathElementsToGcs
SEVERE: Upload failed, will NOT retry staging of classpath: /Users/poiuytrez/Documents/xxx/datascience/DataflowJavaSDK/examples/target/classes
java.io.IOException: Failed to write to GCS path gs://xxx-dataflow/staging/classes-YVxGau7wqYUa4UjU1KkEAg.zip.
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel.throwIfUploadFailed(GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel.java:373)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel.close(GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel.java:270)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.PackageUtil.stageClasspathElementsToGcs(PackageUtil.java:159)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.PackageUtil.stageClasspathElementsToGcs(PackageUtil.java:105)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.GcsStager.stageFiles(GcsStager.java:44)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineRunner.run(DataflowPipelineRunner.java:165)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.run(BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.java:96)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.run(BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.java:47)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:145)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.examples.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:290)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Forbidden",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Forbidden"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:423)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel$UploadOperation.run(GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 53.168 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-03-26T12:11:27+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 24M/603M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any idea of what could be wrong? 
I can do successfully a gsutil cp to copy a file on my google cloud storage bucket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is unexpected. If `gsutil` is able to access the GCS bucket, Dataflow SDK should be able to access it too.

The first thing to try is to update `gcloud`. Please run the following commands:

```
gcloud components update
gcloud auth login
gcloud config set project <your_project_id>
```

Please make you are using your project consistently (in `gcloud config set project`, in `--project` argument to `mvn exec:java`, and that the GCS bucket you are using as a staging location belongs to that project).

Finally, please double-check that you have followed our [Getting Started](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/getting-started) instructions.

If these somewhat generic instructions don't help, please comment back with any additional data and we'll try to get to the bottom of it.

---

UPDATE: After a certain version of `gcloud`, the command to authenticate has changed to:

`gcloud auth application-default login`

The part `application-default` is now required for the SDK to pick up the credential.

Comment: My dataflow account has been updated today. I am not sure if your steps fixed the issues or if it was the activation.

Comment: I have exactly the face the same issue, but the commands above don't help to fix it :(

Comment: You are probably missing application default credentials; the process has slightly changed since this question was posted. Remember to run:     `gcloud auth application-default login`